# php multidimensional form array

Tags: php, arrays

how do I loop through this array and assign the values to a variable and save it to MySQL?

the following array was generated using this form. I don't want to use index keys as the number of values may increase or decrease.

```
<input type="text" name="formB[usr_f_name][]" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" name="formB[usr_l_name][]" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" name="formB[usr_mobile][]" placeholder="Mobile Number" />






Array

(
    [usr_f_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

    [usr_l_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [usr_mobile] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [usr_email] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

This is what I have at the moment. but can't get it working

```
  $id_array = array_keys($_POST['formB']);
  foreach ($id_array as $id){
        $usr_f_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['usr_f_name'][$id]);
        $usr_l_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['usr_l_name'][$id]);
        $usr_mobile =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['usr_mobile'][$id]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO formB SET f_name = '$usr_f_name', l_name = '$usr_l_name', mobile  ='$usr_mobile'";
    }
```

Comment: where is `$id_array` coming from?

Comment: opps -- rectified ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
foreach ($_POST['formB']['usr_f_name'] as $id=>$value){//loop over the values of the usr_f_name and then use the index of that to get the other values
        $usr_f_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['formB']['usr_f_name'][$id]);
        $usr_l_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['formB']['usr_l_name'][$id]);
        $usr_mobile =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['formB']['usr_mobile'][$id]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO formB SET f_name = '$usr_f_name', l_name = '$usr_l_name', mobile  ='$usr_mobile'";
    }
```

Comment: any other way beside looping? NO!

Comment: i mean to say any other looping methods.

Comment: @TheNagaTanker yes there other methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$array = array(     
    'usr_f_name'    => array('first','second'),
    'usr_l_name'    => array('',''),
    'usr_mobile'    => array('',''),
    'usr_email'     => array('',''),
);//Your array

$sql= '';
for($i=0;$i<count($array['usr_f_name']);$i++) 
$sql .= "INSERT INTO formB SET f_name = '".$array['usr_l_name'][$i]."', l_name = '".$array['usr_l_name'][$i]."', mobile  ='".$array['usr_mobile'][$i]."';";
```